# pasar datos del controlador a la vista con el metodo model.addAttribute

Tags: spring

intento pasar los datos desde el controlador a la vista ,al ejecutar el navegador queda en blanco

```
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.web.app.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("titulo","hola spring framework");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

intento mostrar el atributo a través de la etiqueta  thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title th:text="${titulo}"></title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 th:text="${titulo}"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en el RequestMapping te falta indicar el “value” para que entienda a donde tiene que buscar:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index")
```

Espero que te sirva.